# Low performance of Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 is very slow on my machine. I have an i5 with 4 GB Ram.

- I am using Bar mode for vertical scroll bar
- I have disabled CodeLens
- I have also tried the suggestions at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2894215

What other options should be disabled to increase performance?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: An SSD drive can boost the performance.

Comment: yes, i tried rebooting. i am facing problem since i installed it(around 1 month ago).

Comment: @PeterKiss : buying new hardware is not possible right now.

Comment: And what is exactly slow? Startup time? Build time (what kind of preject)? Visual Studio is only running well if the system is on SSD with at least 8 GB memory.

Comment: @PeterKiss : All thing are slow. build time, debugging, code editing(findind, replacing, formatting), if i only open file of with 3-4k line of code CPU usage goes high.
For any slow application, high hardware configuration is solution.
but i think i5 with 4 gb ram, with 7200 rpm HDD is not low configuration for normal developer.

Comment: please check if your system is infected with worm/virus. On my machine, visual studio 2013 only slow at startup, but after that it running fast.

Answer (score 1):

Try Running it in administrator mode, or Change it's compatibility to windows xp service pack 3. You can do that in control pannel or right click on the icon and go to properties and change it in compatability mode.

Comment: No luck with these option too. i tried but it works same as normal mode.

Answer (score -1):

Changing a couple of settings might help:

1. In Visual Studio, Navigate to: Tools > Options...
2. In general group un-check "Enable Rich Client Visual Experience " and "Automatically adjust visual experience" options.

I think this will help.